# How to get a timestamp that is not gullible

Tags: c

I wonder how to get a timestamp that is not gullible. 
(Originally I made it with the functions in time.h but they can be manipulated by hooking.)

Are there any solutions about getting the exact timestamp?

Comment: Can you expand on hooking `time.h` functions ?

Comment: All functions in the standard library, and all systems calls, can be "hooked" in one way or another. Heck, who says you could even [trust your compiler](http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/ken/trust.html)?

Comment: The only way to be and  stay secure, is to look your self inside a room, set up a new machine from scratch and an not connect the machine to the net.

Comment: You need to elaborate your design. In most embedded system which does time critical measuments use hardware interrupts to latch the internal timer to timestamp the measurements. It's not clear what you are trying to do, and in what platform.

Answer (score 2):

getting THE exact timestamp is a science in itself. You can get the exact timestamp of your computer, or you can call a webservice, that sends you the timestamp of the atomic clock (to which you have to compute and adjust the running times of the IP-packets), or you can do a hardware-solution an attach a GPS-Module, which is fairliy accurate.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a C program running in an untrusted environment then there is no way to be sure someone is not providing a fraudulent clock.  To ensure the clock is "reasonable" you would have to contact an external source which you are capable of authenticating (e.g., via SSL/TLS) and read the time from there and see if it differs greatly from what is reported by system calls.  And as @caf noted, even that provides zero guarantees.

Comment: If it's an untrusted environment then you can't trust that any information you have for authenticating the external source (eg a public key) has not been replaced.